# Firebase crashlytics still pending flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

I want to track my flutter Android/IOS crashes in firebase crashlytics , but there is a problem with tracking the first crash on the app and it's still listening to the first crash.

in pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_crashlytics:
firebase_analytics:
firebase_core: ^1.7.0
```

in app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    }
}
```

and in the flutter main.dart :

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
      .setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setUserIdentifier("51");
  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();
```

I even tried android native example crash  `throw new RuntimeExeption("test Firebase crash");`
but firebase is still listening for the first app crash.

**UPDATE**

Firebase Crashlytics page is just like bellow after 48 hours

[pending image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1std.png)

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm in the same position as you, currently with iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
Firebase.initializeApp().then((_) async {
    //enable Crashlytics only when app in release & production
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!kDebugMode);
    //another code here
}
```

Change *!kDebugMode* to *true* if you want to always catch any crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this line in your code .because of this line I think you can't get the crash report. I'm facing the same issue ..and below code is working perfectly fine

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.1'
```

> use this code in app.build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> in Android.build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
}
```

> in you main.dart use this code

```
Future main() async{
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
            
    FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
    runApp(
        MyApp(),
    );
}
```

> and I put this line to crash the app in Splash init function .you can
> use this line where you find suitable

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to filter Non-Fatal errors because the flutter part of the application generates Non-Fatal errors.

Go to firebase console -> crashlytics -> filters -> then choose ->

[image]

Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.0'
}
```

and implementations

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.1'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!But can you explain it a little more? I mean where should I actually filter it? is it in my firebase console? Or something else

Comment: @HusseinDTS it's firebase console, I edited the answer

Comment: OK,but I can't even go to that page. it's a pending page as I mentioned in the Question Update

Comment: Did you added the Json file??

Comment: Yes, I even tried updating the google-service.json by downloading it again. 
I can receive notifications

Comment: @HusseinDTS check my edited answer

Comment: OK. But now I get "can't find google-service.json." but it's already in the app folder. 
firebase messaging is working